# Php getting a value from a text file

Tags: php

I have this script, which works perfectly fine.

```
<?php
$lines_array = file("file.txt");
$search_string = "jummie";

foreach($lines_array as $line) {
if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
    list(, $new_str) = explode(":", $line);
    //$new_str = trim($new_str);
}
}
echo $new_str;
?>
```

If you input this file:

one: number
cheese: word
jummie: foo
bar: ar

It will return foo, for jummie (as seen in the code). Now I have modified the code, but now it does not work anymore:

```
  <?php
   $app_name = $_GET["app"];
    $user_name = $_GET["user"];
    $web_url = $_GET["weburl"];

    $lines_array = file("accounts/userdata/". $user_name ."/". $app_name .".txt");
    $search_string = "keyword";

   foreach($lines_array as $line) {
   if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false) {
    list(, $new_str) = explode(":", $line);
    // If you don't want the space before the word bong, uncomment the following line.
    //$new_str = trim($new_str);
}
}

$new_str = $keyword;

echo $keyword;
?>
```

Does anyone has an idea what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: is it showing any error message?

Comment: what doesn't work mean ? do you get any error, have you checked if the file that you try to grab exists ? have you checked the content of that file ?

Comment: @Nandakumar It does not give any error massage, but it does not give any output or echo to (It should the match).

Comment: @ionutvmi I've tested it, and am sure the file exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that. You've never defined the variable `$keyword` which is what you are ultimately printing.

change the next-to-last line to:

```
$keyword = $new_str
```

Comment: no, you've got the assignment backwards. you are setting $new_str to be the value of $keyword, which is empty.

Comment: Worked! I am really bad with such small details.

Answer (score 0):

Mayhaps you meant to do:

```
$search_string = $keyword;
```

instead of:

```
$search_string = "keyword";
```

?

Comment: No, I really looking for "keyword" and not for $keyword, $keyword is the "output" of keyword